# Use the washer or shell method to find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region R bounded by y = x and y = x^2 about the line x = -1

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

I'm just confused whether I'm going about solving the above problem correctly. We're asked to **set up the integrals only** and **simplify the integrand**. Here's my process:

$$= \pi \int_{0}^{1}(1+\sqrt{y})^2\,dy - \pi \int_{0}^{1}(1+y)^2\,dy$$
$$= \pi \int_{0}^{1}1+2\sqrt{y}+y\,dy - \pi \int_{0}^{1}1+2y+y^2\,dy$$
$$= \pi \int_{0}^{1}1+2\sqrt{y}+y-1-2y-y^2\,dy$$
$$= \pi \int_{0}^{1}2\sqrt{y}-y-y^2\,dy$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes your work is correct using washer method. If you were to use shell method,

height of the shell at a given $x$ is $ ~(x - x^2)$

At the intersection of curves $y = x$ and $y = x^2$,
$y = x = x^2 \implies x = 0 ~$ or $~x = 1$

Also distance of shell from the axis of rotation is $~x - (-1) = 1 + x$

So the integral to find volume using shell method will be,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^1 2 \pi (1+x) ~ (x-x^2) ~ dx = 2 \pi\int_{0}^{1} (x - x^3) ~dx$